# Passing arguments url_for Python

Tags: python, flask

I have two def for creating question and previewing question.

I want to pass a question's ID from `def create()` to `def preview()`. But the `def preview()` cannot realize the ID.

I have try using `return redirect(url_for('preview', question_id=question_id))` and in my `def preview()` I used `question_id = request.args.get('question_id',type=str)`.

How can I fix that?

My code is here:

```
@app.route("/create/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def create():
    question = "How are you?"
    question_id = "123456"
    return redirect(url_for('preview'), question_id=question_id)

@app.route("/preview/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def preview():
    question_id = request.args.get('question_id', type=str)
    print(question_id)
```

Comment: Can you share the error message ? (if there's one)

Comment: By the way, you're passing `question_id` param to the `url_for` function instead of `redirect`. Please correct to : `redirect(url_for('preview'), question_id=question_id)`

Comment: It should show me the ID on the page but it just show me a blank page!

Answer (score 1):

In the preview route, you're doing `print(question_id)` which won't write or render anything to a page, it will only print the value to your console (stdout), that's all.

Try with `render_template_string` like so :

```py
from flask import render_template_string

[...]



@app.route("/preview/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def preview():
    question_id = request.args.get('question_id', type=str)
    return render_template_string('question_id = {{ question_id }}', question_id=question_id)
```

Hope it helps.